# Sumifs looping through multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, loops, sumifs

I work in a contact center and I'm trying to calculate how much time each banker spent on the phones each day.  I have an auto-generated spreadsheet that will provide me the bankers name, date of the call, and how long the call lasted in seconds.  I'm trying to use the sumifs function to give me the answer but I'm having trouble. I could write an If condition for each scenario (e.g.  employee x on day a, employee x on day b, employee x on day c, etc.), but that would take forever as I need it for every day and over 70 employees. Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub ArrayProgram()
Dim days As Variant, bankers As Variant, name As Range, seconds As Range
Dim dte As Range
Set seconds = Range("O:O")
Set name = Range("H:H")
Set dte = Range("B:B")
days = Array("2/13/2017", "2/14/2017", "2/15/2017", "2/16/2017", "2/17/2017", "2/18/2017", "2/19/2017", _
"2/20/2017", "2/21/2017", "2/22/2017", "2/23/2017", "2/24/2017", "2/25/2017", "2/26/2017", "2/27/2017", _ "2/28/2017")
employees = Array("Bobby, Daniel, Michel, Shayla, Bernard, Eboni, Sam, Vincent")
```

I want to write a loop that will run through the arrays outputting this formula:

> =sumifs(seconds, name range, name, date range, date)

Is this the correct approach or am I missing something?

Comment: It isnt clear.. You already have that in your spread sheet. The duration of call with the specific date

Comment: That is correct, however, I'm trying to find the total length of all calls for each banker on each day.  Each employee may have anywhere from 10-70 calls per day.  I need the sum of each banker on each day so I can show a linear progression of volume increase.